# issue with angular 4 and nodejs , serve index.html based on URL like /admin and /

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Hi i have setup three project api(nodejs) , admin(angular 4) and website(angular 4) , after build i got two UI folder admin-dist and web-dist , I want to access these app based on URL '/admin' will access admin-dist and '/' will access web-dist , I have placed these two folder on of api folder

For accessing these app i have written node code like this ,But i am not able to access ,
Please help me, Thanks in advance  ..

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
router = express.Router();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var fs = require('fs')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var path = require('path')

var cors = require('cors');
var User = require('./models/user.model');
var dbConfig = require('./config/db');

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), {flags: 'a'});
// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.db, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('faild to connect with mongo DB', err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Connection open with mongo db');
    }
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());









app.use('/api', router);
var userRoute = require('./routes/user.route')(router);
// var profileRoute = require('./routes/profile.route')(app);
// var productRoute=require('./routes/products.route')(app);




app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/admin-dist'));
app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
    console.log('admin route');
  return  res.sendFile(path.resolve('./admin-dist/index.html'));
});
app.get('/admin/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./admin-dist/index.html'));
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/front-dist'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('web route');
    return  res.sendFile(path.resolve('./front-dist/index.html'));
});
app.use('/*',function(req, res) {
   return  res.sendFile(path.resolve('./front-dist/index.html'));
});





app.listen(port, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Server api runing on port ', port);
    }
})
```

Comment: I am able to access index.html ,But app routes are not working

Comment: ng build admin and from-end with base href like
`ng build --base-href /admin-dist/` and `ng build --base-href /front-dist/`

Comment: Thanks @Yatin for replying me , I have tried like this but it's not working for me , still having same issue